# How do I modify appearance of jquery ui widgets

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI. Current issue I'm having is font size inside a dialog. When I use the standard settings the font size is far too big.
What I did is I used the element inspector to find the class name of the corresponding div and I added a .ui-widget-something { font-size: 62.5% } to my css. This works fine. Is this the only way to change the font or is there another way?

Comment: That way seems just fine.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font size in a different ways, for example:

```
font-size:20px;
font-size:1.4em;
font-size:30%;
```